# Custom N1QL query in couchbase using spring boot JAVA

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I was playing with couchbase using  http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-couchbase.But I am stuck with running custom N1QL queries.

I wrote this in repository

```
@Query("SELECT l.created_on,l.is_public,l.list_id,l.list_name,l.type,l.user_id,META(u).id AS _ID, META(u).cas AS _CAS FROM lists USE INDEX(lists USING GSI) WHERE type='list' AND user_name=$userName AND `list_name`=$listName")
public Lists checkListName(@Param("userName") String userName, @Param("listName") String listName);
```

But I am getting this

Unable to retrieve enough metadata for N1QL to entity mapping, have you selected _ID and _CAS?

Is their another way or what should I do to run this query.

Comment: How the "Lists" object looks like? could you share more code?